# Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

i have this error in laravel eloquent query :

"Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column"

```
    $data = DB::table('passages')
        ->select('passages.*','users.name','users.family','valid_users.user_id','valid_users.valid_card_id','valid_users.valid_card_decimal','valid_users.valid_card_hex')
        ->join('valid_users','valid_users.id','=','passages.valid_user_id')
        ->join('users','valid_users.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->join('accounts','accounts.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->whereIn('accounts.role_id',$roles)
        ->groupBy('valid_user_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: You have the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option enabled in your MySQL, which removes MySQL's relaxed rules about GROUP BY. What version of MySQL are you using it?

Comment: If you are using a MySQL version higher than 5.7 the default value is ON, before this version the default value was OFF.

Comment: There are no aggregation functions in the query so a group by is not appropriate - what are you trying to do?

Comment: mysql version is higher than 5.7

Comment: i want the last row of passages for each user. groupBy "passages.valid_user_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to find the last row is to use a correlated sub query which identifies last (assuming you have a way of doing so) in this example last is identified as the max auto_incremented id

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t( id  int auto_increment primary key, userid  int, val varchar(10));
insert into t (userid,val) values
(1,100),(2,10),(1,15),(2,20);

select t.* 
from t
where id = (select max(id) from t t1 where t1.userid = t.userid);

+----+--------+------+
| id | userid | val  |
+----+--------+------+
|  3 |      1 | 15   |
|  4 |      2 | 20   |
+----+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

whenever we use Group by clause then rest of the columns we are selecting must be with aggegate function (like:  min,max,avg,sum).

example :

```
select sum(t.name),t.age
from table1 t
group by t.age
```